# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voice')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make https://coderadio.freecodecamp.org/ play in a discord voice channel. I want to add a command called /coderadio that calls the bot into the current voice channel and streams the current song on the radio.

Here is the repo I used originally - https://github.com/TannerGabriel/discord-bot

I have added a new file to the commands folder, play-coderadio.js. I am hoping to have one slash command to play the radio and another to stop it.

index.js -

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = require('./client/Client');
const config = require('./config.json');
const {Player} = require('discord-player');

const client = new Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

console.log(client.commands);

const player = new Player(client);

player.on('error', (queue, error) => {
  console.log(`[${queue.guild.name}] Error emitted from the queue: ${error.message}`);
});

player.on('connectionError', (queue, error) => {
  console.log(`[${queue.guild.name}] Error emitted from the connection: ${error.message}`);
});

player.on('trackStart', (queue, track) => {
  queue.metadata.send(`▶ | Started playing: **${track.title}** in **${queue.connection.channel.name}**!`);
});

player.on('trackAdd', (queue, track) => {
  queue.metadata.send(` | Track **${track.title}** queued!`);
});

player.on('botDisconnect', queue => {
  queue.metadata.send('❌ | I was manually disconnected from the voice channel, clearing queue!');
});

player.on('channelEmpty', queue => {
  queue.metadata.send('❌ | Nobody is in the voice channel, leaving...');
});

player.on('queueEnd', queue => {
  queue.metadata.send('✅ | Queue finished!');
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('ready', function() {
  client.user.setActivity(config.activity, { type: config.activityType });
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
  console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
  console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
  if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

  if (message.content === '!deploy' && message.author.id === client.application?.owner?.id) {
    await message.guild.commands
      .set(client.commands)
      .then(() => {
        message.reply('Deployed!');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        message.reply('Could not deploy commands! Make sure the bot has the application.commands permission!');
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName.toLowerCase());

  try {
    if (interaction.commandName == 'ban' || interaction.commandName == 'userinfo') {
      command.execute(interaction, client);
    } else {
      command.execute(interaction, player);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    interaction.followUp({
      content: 'There was an error trying to execute that command!',
    });
  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

play-coderadio.js -

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'coderadio',
    description: 'play FCC radio',
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if(!voiceChannel)
    return message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel!"); 
    
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if(!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.reply('I am missing permission!');    

    var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
    await connection.voice.setSelfDeaf(true);
    connection.play("https://coderadio-relay-blr.freecodecamp.org/radio/8010/radio.mp3").setVolumeLogarithmic(1);
    const embed =  new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Radio Now Playing!`)
    .setDescription(`Now Playing radio!\n\nPlaying into ${voiceChannel.name}`)
    message.channel.send(embed)
}
}
```

Here is the error I am getting when I run /coderadio -

*C:\Users\Rudy\musicbot\discord-bot\commands\play-coderadio.js:9 const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voice') at Object.execute (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\commands\play-coderadio.js:9:41) at module.exports. (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\index.js:89:15) at module.exports.emit (node:events:527:28) at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:74:12) at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10) at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users--\musicbot\discord-bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18) at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for your assignment to voiceChannel.

Something like
`const voiceChannel = message?.member?.voice?.channel;`

In cases where there is no message, voiceChannel will render `false` and you will send the error message you stated in your if statement